# PHP intersect of array of array

Tags: php, intersection

I have an array of array . 
Example like

```
a[0]={1,2,3};
a[1]={2,3,4};
**Edit** in a[2] from a[2]={4,5};
a[2]={2,4,5};
and more
```

How can I find common element which exist in all array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid foreach loop by

```
call_user_func_array('array_intersect',$a);
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a function I have made. It's just a reference for a multidimensional array.

```
<?php
$array1 = array('angka'=>12,'satu','2'=>'dua','tiga'=>array('dua','enam','empat'=>array('satu','lima',12)));//object
$array2 = array('dua','tiga','empat',12);//object as intersect refference

function intersect($data=NULL)
{
    if(!empty($data))
    {
        $crashed = array();
        $crashed2 = array();
        foreach($data[0] as $key=>$val)
        {
            if(!is_array($val))
            {
                $crashed[$key] = in_array($val,$data[1]);//return true if crashed (intersect)
            }
            else
            {
                $crashed2[$key] = intersect(array($val,$data[1]));
            }
            $crashed = array_merge($crashed,$crashed2);
        }
    }
    return $crashed;
}
$intersect = intersect(array($array1,$array2));
print_r($intersect);
?>
```

It returns a result like this:

```
Array ( [angka] => 1 [0] => [1] => 1 [tiga] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => [empat] => Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => 1 ) ) )
```

It returns true if the value of an array matches with a reference array.

Hope the code can help you.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look here [`array-intersect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php).
You could use it like this:

```
$intersect = $a[0];
for ($i = 1; $i < count($a); $i++)
{
    $intersect = array_intersect($intersect, $a[$i]);
}
```

Comment: @Vivek, Aha. How about using a loop ?

Comment: Read the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php it works on as many arrays as you want.

Comment: @vascowhite that's true .. But probably the length of the array `$a` is variable, so he can't just do `array_intersect($a[0], $a[1], ...., $a[50])`

Comment: nice . but I will use foreach loop.

Comment: @Anna I see what u mean, looks like a custom function will be needed.

Comment: @vasco: FWIW, in this case one could use `call_user_func_array('array_intersect', a)`.

Comment: @Felix Klink I think I am doing wrong . but that code don't works . 
http://codepad.org/rCMoGQ0Y

Comment: @Anna sorry call_user_func_array('array_intersect',$a); this is more better approach so selected that answer.

Answer (score 0):

As the name suggest, I think you can just use [array-intersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

From that page:

```
<?php
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue");
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
?>
```

gives

```
Array
(
    [a] => green
    [0] => red
)
```